# sql query to codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how do i write this in codeigniter active records?

```
  MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_members.conversation_last_view AS conversation_unread
```

I tried this `$this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date' > 'conversations_messages.conversation_last_view', 'conversation_unread');`

but it said **The query you submitted is not valid.
Filename: C:\wamp\www\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 184**

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: how do i check the time value of the message date greater than the value of the message last read time value . note that am using max because the sql function isnt a date or time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

already solved it. these might help someone someday

```
  MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_members.conversation_last_view AS conversation_unread 


 $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date > conversations_members.conversation_last_view', 'conversation_unread');
```